# Unable to hold 19 digit value in int64 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a long data type and i tried to pass below value.

> 9947493585485901500

But i'm getting following error

```
Error converting value "9947493585485901500" to type 'System.Int64'. Path '[0].gId', line 1, position 108.
```

Can't int64 type hold the above value ? if yes.then which data type should i use for this ?

Comment: Is there an actual need to use *numbers* of that magnitude and accuracy? Sometimes requirements state "number" when they should say "string".

Comment: why not trying to [google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.maxvalue?view=net-5.0) it first see if it can fit your value ? it takes 2 seconds

Comment: If you **try** to do it: `long x = 9947493585485901500;`, does it work? No? What does the compiler error tell you?

Comment: It fits in an unsigned long - `ulong l = 9947493585485901500;`

Comment: @stuartd sure it would work but in no way he need to use such big number lol. He is probably doing something wrong in order to need that.

Comment: There is BigInteger class for such purposes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton there are legit use cases for big numbers. For example in cryptography. RSA uses prime numbers with size of order of 1000 bits (much bigger than number from question), and performs mathematical operations on them.

Comment: @Evk Yes. Does the OP have such a case?

Comment: I guess I replied to @Franck "but in no way he need to use such big number"

Answer (score 3):

int64 is 64 bits. 2^64 = 18446744073709551616 which is the maximum number of unique values that can be represented by 64 bits.

int64 need also represent negative numbers, halving that to 9223372036854775808

You will need to use slightly lower numbers

Comment: Strictly speaking `long.MaxValue` is 922337203685477580**7**

Answer (score 0):

Information about C# ranges and sizes of data types you can find in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types). Range for int64 is `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.